# how to print value from out of main method toinside main method

Tags: android

how to access value which is out of main class? i want to print value of elementarytxtview
in main class in  parameter but is print null value of in parameter i want to pass elementarytextview value in parameter to other activity

```
     public class HomeMenu extends Activity {
ImageButton imgNews, imgContact, imgSetting;
ListView listMainMenu;
ListView Middleschoollist, HighSchoollist, Atipicalschoollist;
String status;
firstscreenadapter mma;
String SelectMenuAPI;
String SelectMenuAPI2;
String url1;
String elementry;

// String High;
String message;
TextView Elementarytxt, Middletxt, Hightxt, Atypicaltxt;
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
String elementarytxtview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreenfinal);

    ExpandableHeightListView listMainMenu = (ExpandableHeightListView) 
   findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu11);
    ExpandableHeightListView Middleschoollist = (ExpandableHeightListView) 
    findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu22);
    ExpandableHeightListView HighSchoollist = (ExpandableHeightListView) 
   findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu33);
    ExpandableHeightListView Atipicalschoollist = (ExpandableHeightListView) 
         findViewById(R.id.listMainMenu44);

    Elementarytxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Elementaryschool);
    Middletxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MiddleSchool);
    Hightxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HighSchool);
    Atypicaltxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AtipicalSchool);

    mma = new firstscreenadapter(this);

    if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(HomeMenu.this)) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeMenu.this, "NO NETWORK Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (!Utils.isUserOnline(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NETWORK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    url1 = "http://198.57.208.46/~school/ajax.php?action=get_school";


    listMainMenu.setAdapter(mma);
    Middleschoollist.setAdapter(mma);
    HighSchoollist.setAdapter(mma);
    Atipicalschoollist.setAdapter(mma);


    listMainMenu.setExpanded(true);
    Middleschoollist.setExpanded(true);
    HighSchoollist.setExpanded(true);
    Atipicalschoollist.setExpanded(true);
    Toast.makeText(this, elementarytxtview, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    listMainMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(HomeMenu.this, 
          SecondStep.class);
iMenuList.putExtra("category_name",xxx.xxx.xxxx/~school/index.php
  /api/index/getschools?mg="+ Category_name.get(position)+  "&sl="+elementarytxtview);

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

    parseJSONData();
}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();

}

public void parseJSONData() {

    SelectMenuAPI = Utils.Homemenu2;
    SelectMenuAPI2 = Utils.Homemenu;

    clearData();

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(SelectMenuAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client2.getParams(),
                15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client2.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request2 = new HttpGet(SelectMenuAPI2);
        HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(request2);
        InputStream atomInputStream2 = response2.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream2));

        String line2;
        String str2 = "";
        while ((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
            str2 += line2;
        }

        JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);
        // message = json2.getString("message");
        status = json3.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school2 = json3.getJSONArray("data");

            String[] mVal = new String[school2.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                mVal[i] = 
          school2.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");

                Elementarytxt.setText(mVal[0]);

                Middletxt.setText(mVal[1]);
                Hightxt.setText(mVal[2]);
                Atypicaltxt.setText(mVal[3]);

            }

            elementarytxtview = mVal[0];
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);
        // message = json2.getString("message");
        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            // JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

                // 
         Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("title"));

            }

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

      }
```

Comment: how to get string value from out of main method to inside main method???

Comment: toast should be after settext() to textview.

Comment: Perhaps, call `parseJSONData()` before showing the toast? And _please_ learn how to format the code.

Comment: Please format the code properly with proper alignment and indention. So that people here can save time figuring out your code.

Comment: Call `Toast.makeText(this, elementarytxtview, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` after `parseJsonData();` in `HomeMenu.java`.

Comment: Please try to put some effort in constructing your question as a whole next time. Try googling for `Intent` examples. That is what you need to transfer data between `Activities`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure of what you mean.

But if you want to access variables easily between classes, you should make the `String elementarytxtview;` `public static`

Thereby: `public static String elementarytxtview;`

What that means is basically that the `variable` is shared and can be used between all classes. Just by writing `HomeMenu.elementarytxtview;` in your case.

Comment: i want to print vlaue from out of main class
{
}
get value form here below main method

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. If you want to perform something like `System.out.println("");` to print/debug info, you need to place them inside the main or other methods. Just place it in your method can call upon the variable you want information about.

Comment: check my updated code i want to pass in elementarytextview value in parameter to other actiivity

Comment: To another activity? That's the first time you ever mention that. This is why you should ask a question with more than 2 lines of text.

Comment: Well yea that makes a total difference like @EdwardvanRaak just said.

Comment: check my updated code  i want to pass elementarytext value in parameter to other activity

Comment: You should fix you question immediately, since what you want, isn't what you said in the question.

Comment: i frist simplyfy my code to understanding but thisismy actually code i want to get value formout of main  method

Comment: You just said and I quote "i want to pass in elementarytextview value in parameter to other actiivity", so you want to send/pass variables between activities, you didn't say anything about that in the question. People need to know what, or it will be impossible to give you the answer you are searching for!

Comment: see my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373997/how-ot-get-value-form-of-string-out-of-mainactivity i brifly decribe my problem there

Answer (score 1):

`elementarytxtview` is not initialized before you try to show it via `Toast`. At first you need to put some value in it.

Comment: i initialized on top    String elementarytxtview;

Comment: @user2699824 You have just declared but not initialized the `elementarytxtview` variable. Try showing the `Toast` message after `parseJSONData()` is called.

Comment: It is not initialize it is just declared.

Comment: check my updated code i want to pass in elementarytextview value in parameter to other actiivity

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the Toast in the `onCreate` method which runs before your `parseJSONData()` method. You haven't initialized `String elementarytxtview` therefore it will show null because you only declared the variable.